# How to add image to Swagger UI autodocs using FastAPI?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, fastapi, openapi

I would like to add an image to the FastAPI automatic documentation (provided by Swagger UI), but I can't figure out how to do this.
This is the code:

```
@api.get(path='/carbon-credit/',
    responses={
        200: {'description': 'Ok',
            "content": {
            "image/jpeg": {
                "example": 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'
                    }
                }},
        404: {"description": "not found"},
        422: {'description': 'not found 2'},
    },
    name='API for Carbon Credit',
    description="get carbon credit",
    tags=['Images'],
    response_class=Response)
```

As you can see from the code, I'm trying to do this using a URL, and what I get in both ReDoc and Swagger UI is just the URL as a text, not the actual image. Also, I would like to use an image stored in the local drive.

Screenshots from Swagger UI and ReDoc:
[image: ReDoc]

[image: Swagger]

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to serve a similar image redirected to a different page, standalone image maybe? or in a separate html page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [Swagger UI and ReDoc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs) use standard HTML tags for the `description` parameter. Hence, you can add the image using the `description`.

```py
@app.get(path='/',
    responses={
        200: {'description': '<img src="https://placebear.com/cache/395-205.jpg" alt="bear">',
    ...
```

OpenAPI also supports markdown elements (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929108)) and will render the image for you in Swagger UI/ReDoc. Hence, you can alternatively use:

```py
@app.get(path='/',
    responses={
        200: {'description': '![bear](https://placebear.com/cache/395-205.jpg)',
    ...
```

To use an **image stored in the local drive**, you can mount a [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) instance to a specific path (let's say `/static`) to serve static files/images from a directory in your drive. Example below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

@app.get(path='/',
    responses={
        200: {'description': '![bear](static/bear.jpg)',
    ...
```

#### Add the image to the examples field

To add the image to the `examples` field you can again use the `description` parameter, as shown below. Make sure you do that through the `examples` parameter, not `example`.

```py
@app.get(path='/',
    responses={
        200: {"description": "OK",
               "content": {
                  "image/jpeg": {
                     "schema": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "binary"
                     },
                     "examples": {
                        "sampleImage": {
                           "summary": "A sample image",
                           "description": "![bear](https://placebear.com/cache/395-205.jpg)",
                           "value": ""
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
        404: {"description": "not found"},
        422: {'description': 'not found 2'},
    },
    ...
```

Comment: And what if I want to add the image in the example field?

Comment: Exhaustive and comprehensive answer. 
Thank you so much!